# Limit of $2^{n^2/2}\sum_{j=1}^{n/2} \sum_{k=1}^{n/2}\left(\cos^2(\frac{j \pi}{n+1}) + \cos^2(\frac{k \pi}{n+1})\right)$ as a double integral

Tags: integration, limits, summation, riemann-sum

I am currently looking into Dimer coverings and my next step is to find how the following limit is calculated:
$$\begin{align*}
L &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\ln\left(2^{n^2/2}\prod_{j=1}^{n/2} \prod_{k=1}^{n/2}\left(\cos^2(\frac{j \pi}{n+1}) + \cos^2(\frac{k \pi}{n+1})\right)\right) \\[1ex]
&= \frac{1}{16 \pi^2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\ln[4+2\cos(x) + 2\cos(y)] \, dx \, dy
\end{align*}$$

I think I got quite far, but there is some error in my calculation, which gives the required result, but the lower bound of my integrals is 0 instead of $- \pi$. I will write my calculations down here. If anyone finds what I did wrong, please tell me. It would help a lot.

$$\begin{align*}
L &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \ln\left(2^{n^2/2}\prod_{j=1}^{n/2} \prod_{k=1}^{n/2} \left(\cos^2\left(\frac{j \pi}{n+1}\right) + \cos^2\left(\frac{k \pi}{n+1}\right)\right)\right) \\[1ex]
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{j=1}^{n/2} \sum_{k=1}^{n/2}\ln\left(4\left(\cos^2\left(\frac{j \pi}{n+1}\right) + \cos^2\left(\frac{k \pi}{n+1}\right)\right)\right) \\[1ex]
&= \frac{1}{4 \pi^2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(4(\cos^2(x)+\cos^2(y)) \, dx \, dy \\[1ex]
&= \frac{1}{4 \pi^2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln\left(4\left(\frac12\cos(2x)+\frac12+\frac12\cos(2y)+\frac12\right)\right) \, dx \, dy\\
&= \frac{1}{4 \pi^2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(2\cos(2x)+2\cos(2y)+4) \, dx \, dy\\
&= \frac{1}{16 \pi^2} \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \ln(2\cos(x)+2\cos(y)+4) \, dx \, dy
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I'll venture a guess and say that it may be the $1/4$ appearing on the second line? Since $\cos$ is even, the integrated function on the last line is even regarding both coordinates $x$ and $y$, and so its current integral should be one-fourth of its integral with $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}$, meaning you are currently multiplicatively $1/4$ away from the solution I think.

Comment: How does one go from the second line from the top to the third line from the top when converting the double sum into a double integral?

Comment: I'm curious about the conversion from product to sum. Shouldn't it be$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^2}\ln\left(2^{n^2/2}\Pi\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(2^{n^2/2})+\ln(\Pi)}{n^2}=\frac{\ln(2)}2+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Sigma\ln}{n^2}\quad?$$